Is there any case that under some transformation the action is not invariant but the full path integral measure is invariant?
Suppose we make some field transformation (it may be an argument transformation like translation or the functional form transformation like $U(1)$ transformation or containing both like Lorentz transformation).
In classical field theories, symmetry is defined by the statement that the invariance of action. i.e. $\delta S=0$.
In quantum theories, the definition of symmetry is (at least for me) the invariance of the full path integral measure $D\phi\ e^{iS[\phi]}$. Nontrivial transformation of $D\phi$ may cause the anomaly.
My question is: there are any cases where some transformation causes both $S$ and $D\phi$ to change (so it is not symmetry classically), but leaves their product $D\phi\ e^{iS[\phi]}$ unchanged?
I know the case of Chern-Simons theory; in this case, the action itself is not invariant but $e^{iS}$ is invariant under gauge transformations because $\delta S=2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ with suitable normalization. But is there any case that the $D\phi$ and $e^{iS}$ are both changed (unlike Chern-Simons theory) and somehow these changes were canceled in their product?

related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/403987/84967

I can think of one common occurrence. The "inverse anomaly" situation you describe arises at the fixed point of the renormalization group. When we consider $\phi^4$ theory in $4 - \epsilon$ dimensions, the classical action is not scale invariant when $\epsilon \neq 0$. Indeed, we often write it as
\begin{align}
S = \int d^{4 - \epsilon}x \; \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi + \mu^\epsilon \frac{g_0}{4!} \phi^4.
\end{align}
This appears to depend on the scale $\mu$ no matter what we set $g_0$ to. In particular, we can set it to $g Z_g$ for some $Z_g = O(\epsilon^{-1})$ which is cooked up to cancel poles in some loop diagrams ($\overline{MS}$ scheme). But we know that if we do this and further set $g = (4\pi)^2 \epsilon / 3$ (plus higher powers of $\epsilon$ that are harder to compute), we will be at a zero of
\begin{align}
\beta(g) = -\epsilon g + \frac{3 g^2}{(4\pi)^2} + O(g^3)
\end{align}
and therefore restore scale invariance at the quantum level.
